# Connecting two HDMI monitors to Late 2012 Mac mini

Tags: display, mac-mini, hdmi

I have two Samsung monitors with HDMI input.

Is it possible to connect them simultaneously to my Mac mini using HDMI? I wish to have a extended desktop setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! Get a mDP (Mini DisplayPort) to HDMI cable. Then plug that into the Thunderbolt port, and run the other monitor from the HDMI port.

Here’s an arbitrary example of a [mDP-HDMI cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007RQ3J7G).